# How to send a proactive message with BotFramework which will trigger an alert on Teams and will be shown in "Activities" tab?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I would like to alert users of my bot, about some kind of danger. I am using the proactive message mechanism to inform the users if something happens. The messages are delivered correctly, but i see no possibility to trigger an alert on the message in MS Teams and show it in activities tab. I've tried to change the Importance of the MessageActivity to "high" but this has not helped. How to configure/format the message to achieve such a behavior? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

-You can [@mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#-mentions) the user in personal scope(1:1) conversation along with your message

-Whenever bot get installed either in team or personal, you need to get  ServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), ConversationId(turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id) and
TeamId(optional if you want to share something in channel - var teamsDetails = turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo();)

-Follow this doc to [Send proactive notification to the users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). For ConversationReference here's the code snippet on how you can create it.

```
var conversationReference = new ConversationReference() 

    {
        Bot = new ChannelAccount() { Id = $"28:{botId}" },
        ChannelId = "msteams",
        ServiceUrl = serviceUrl,
    }
```

`conversationReference.Conversation = new ConversationAccount() { Id = conversationId };` // for personal.

`conversationReference =  new ConversationAccount() { ConversationType = conversationType , IsGroup = true, Id = teamsDetails.Id, TenantId = tenantId };` // for team or group.

Answer (score 0):

If you can mention the user in the chat message (even though it's 1:1), it will appear in the Activity Feed. I have not actually done this myself, but Microsoft has some documentation on [Constructing mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#constructing-mentions).

I tried to do a real quick PoC using `<at>@username</at>` in a message using standard activity handler but it doesn't work. But if you are able to follow the linked messages you should be able to achieve this.